# What code do I have to write within for loop?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I need the output like below, how can I do that?

```
       name1
         title1
         title2

       name2
         title1
         title2
```

In that for loop I have to display the title. Here I have used below code which means I am getting the following error:

`'char' does not contain a definition for 'Attribute' and no extension method 'Attribute' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference`

How can I resolve above error and how can I write the condition within a for loop for displaying the title?

I have used this code:

```
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notchs));
   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(dataInXmlFile);
   var Categories = (from Category in xmlDoc.Descendants("Category")
               select new Notch()
               {
                       name = (string)Category.Attribute("name"),
                       title =  Category.Elements("Articles").Elements("article").ToString()            
               }).ToList();
       foreach(var doc in Categories)
        {
            foreach(var sec in doc.title)
            {
                sec.Attribute("title").Value.ToList(),
            }
        }
        NotchsList.ItemsSource = Categories.ToList();
```

XML

```
<Categories>
  <Category name="notchbolly">
   <Articles>
   <article articleid="170" title="Colour And Vibrancy Are Part Of Our DNA">...</      article>
   <article articleid="187" title="German chef gets saucy!!">...</article>
   <article articleid="2004" title="Meet-the-Face-of-Compassion">...</article>
   <article articleid="2005" title="Dutt’s-family-gets-together!">...</article>
   <article articleid="1933" title="NOTCH easy to do recipe- Mushroom Risotto with   truffles">...</article>
   <article articleid="1934" title="NOTCH easy to do recipe- Lobster with Black ink Linguini Arabiatta">...</article>
  <article articleid="1935" title="Yash Birla- 100% Living">...</article>
  </Articles>
</Category>
<Category name="notchfashion">
  <Articles>
  <article articleid="81" title="Making Headlines">...</article>
  <article articleid="99" title="Ladakh through my Lens">...</article>
  <article articleid="689" title="A-Family-Affair">...</article>
  <article articleid="2264" title="Sushmita-back-with-Manav?">...</article>
  <article articleid="70" title="NOTCH- Making of the cover- Farhan Akhtar & Javed Akhtar">...</article>
   <article articleid="78" title="NOTCH easy to do recipe- Aubergine Carpaccio">...       </article>
  <article articleid="1935" title="Yash Birla- 100% Living">...</article>
 </Articles>
</Category>
```

Comment: I've update answer to match you xml

Comment: hi lazyberezovsky this is challenging task for me i have complete with in 2 days,so please try to give me one solution

Comment: I don't see several solutions here. Do you? Also if this is your challenging task, than you supposed to be one, who will take an effort to complete task

Comment: @nagaraj I am observing your questions in the past few days, you seem to be very ignorant. Please do some research about xml parsing. Try some samples. Learn it and then implement on your problem. Also, learn how to debug a Visual Studio project efficiently. Good luck :)

Comment: yes off course,but am new for windows phone and i dont have long time to learn i have deadline so i have complete within deadline and side by side am trying some examples but i cant get it so i except to experienced people

Answer (score 5):

In your code `title` property is a string, not list of strings. So, in inner foreach you are trying to enumerate string char by char. Also you are tyring to get attribute from that `char` in loop. And of course, `char` is not `XElement`, it do not have `Attribute` method.

Use a list of string instead (and use PascalCase names for properties).

```
// why are you named class Notch? use Category!
public class Notch 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

Something like that (can't tell for sure without seeing your xml):

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(dataInXmlFile);
var Categories = 
    (from Category in xmlDoc.Descendants("Category")
     select new Notch()
     {
         Name = (string)Category.Attribute("name"),
         Titles = Category.Element("Articles").Elements("article")
                          .Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("title")).ToList()
     }).ToList();

 foreach(var category in Categories)
 {
    foreach(var title in category.Titles)
    {
         // use title
    }
 }

NotchsList.ItemsSource = Categories.ToList();
```

One more advice - use short names for short-scope variables (like range variables in Linq queries). So, for example above, instead of `Category` variable, you can use simple `c`.

UPDATE Keep in mind that you have unescaped ampersand in your xml. Ampersands [should be escaped](http://www.microshell.com/programming/php/xml-and-ampersand/) with `&amp;`.

Comment: @nagaraj sorry, don't understand you. `title` is string, use it.

Comment: hi how can i use this title with in foeach loop ?i got some error.., please help me ..,

Comment: @nagaraj how would I guess what error do you have and how you want to use title in loop?

Comment: s,how can i use title in foreach loop?

Comment: @nagaraj have you tried using it? what exact problem do you have?

Comment: i used title in foreach loop,like console.writeLine(title);no errors shows but output coming only category name

Comment: @nagaraj make sure you do not have namespaces in your xml, and that names of attributes and elements are same as in sample above. E.g. if you have attribute `Title` instead of `title`, then `(string)a.Attribute("title")` will return null

Comment: ok i got great hopeful for your guidance but my result is coming on like category name and then system.collection.generic its not convert list to string i guess

Comment: please don't mine where is that code @lazyberezovsky because am using stack flow only few days so ......,

Comment: @nagaraj OK, if you have some errors, don't say `I have some error` - write in comment to solution line of code which produces error, and exception message, that you received. Btw I see you have lot of unaccepted questions, so if there is any question which answered your question, you should accept that.

Comment: sorry am new for windows phone development

Comment: i got output like this                                 notchbolly(This is correct)                                System.Collections.Generic.List(here i want to show title) so please tell me what i want do??? this is my problem..,

Comment: @nagaraj *please tell me what i want do* ? I don't know what you want to do

Comment: @nagaraj please, read your own comments, and think about information you provided to me. Code above works without any problems, verified. Also your xml is incorrect in two places (ampersand and wrong closing tag of first article). Sorry, I believe you can make working code work for your challenging task.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky +1 for your patience dude.

Comment: @nkchandra I'm amazed that somebody have read all these comments!

Comment: +1 for trying to help him although he doesn't show any effort on his own.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks, Daniel! I also flagged him for moderators. Really strange man, he really completely do not know C# and keep asking same question over and over again..

Comment: He will eventually be banned. The sad thing is that he won't even understand why. People so blatanly ignoring the rules have their ignorance sitting so deep that they aren't aware of it anymore.